# Inkscape or something better?

Tags: vector, inkscape, free, applications

Is Inkscape good for creating 8bit graphic for mobile games? If not, what's better? I'm looking for a fully legal program, I know how to use Gimp but there's no vector graphic option.

Comment: 8bit is usually a raster technique--not vector. I assume you're looking to make pixelated illustrations? If so, I'd really suggest the raster option (The GIMP/PhotoShop/Paint.net/Pixelmator/etc)

Comment: I want to make graphic like in flappy bird, so not so hard to make, there's another question, i want to make money by ads, is there any problems with programs you suggested?

Comment: so, flappy bird would be a raster animated sprite. So stick with the raster tools. I think you'll find it much easier than trying to draw pixels with a vector tool. As for the software you use to make the artwork, there's no correlation to putting ads into your game.

Comment: I don't think the tool do the craftsman, nor the habit do the monk. That said, I think in general no matter what software you use, at least not at an early stage. I would suggest start with free software such as GIMP and Inkscape, so no need to waste money paying expensive licenses. If at some later stage do not satisfy the workflow with free software you could see any solution software from Adobe or Corel.

Comment: No Flappy Bird is not raster. Those are vector sprites. You can convert a vector image to a raster whenever you need to, but not the other way, so you always want to work in vectors when you are making graphics. Even if you want to make a pixelated effect, you do that with vectors so that you can make that pixelated effect at any size you may need later.

Answer (score 1):

Aradnix makes a point that really resonates with my experience.

I started off in the Computer Graphics Design world in 1987 while attending The Univ. of Tennessee. The first CG program I used was AutoCad (I think ver. 2.0). At the time there really wasn't any useful raster graphics program available, nor any need for one. By 1989 Win 3.0 showed up and CorelDraw. Still no really useful bitmap program other than A program called Targa (I think), and Ventura Publisher (page design). Both of these were run from the DOS prompt. I could go on with the history lesson, but the point is you learn a trade with the tools you learned the trade with. I stayed with AutoCad and CorelDraw for a long time - even after Adobe started showing some real promise - because I could scale objects and move them around.

In short, this was how my mind worked, vector graphics helped me wrap my mind around a design I liked. At 8bit you really don't have too many choices for color combinations anyway. However, If one is skilled with Photoshop, or Gimp you can accomplish the same things I once did with CorelDraw.

Joe (now retired at age 74)

Comment: Please do not add your email here. Welcome!

Comment: Thanks Zach, I really wasn't planning on registering, jus wanted to remain a "Guest", hence the EmailAddr. Now I'm registered as TennesseeJoe. I'll fix up my profile if allowed.

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Stack Exchange only allows one account per user on a site.  Please go to our [help section](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is one of free powerful grahic editors out there is good for vector graphics that can be exported as bitmaps (raster) and used as sprites if you want.

Comment: ...but that isn't the same as creating "8-bit" graphics, of which I would argue Inkscape is not the right tool for.

Comment: Oh yeah you can, the grid can help you to design 8-bit graphics just display the grid you check this video to have an idea

Comment: oh for sure, you *can*. It's just that I'd argue if your goal is low-fi raster art, using a raster tool in the first place will be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing anything in your computer, try the browser based sprite editor [BobSprite](http://www.bobsprite.com).

I found this to be very helpful.

It has an amazing Undo system (you can undo and redo pixel by pixel) among other nice features.

***I am affiliated with this tool.***